# Set Image source inside a Button in ColumnHeaderStyle Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I basecally want the headers of the columns perform as a button, I tought using a a ColumnHEaderStyle would be easy but I think I'm missing something

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeadTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid Height="82">
                        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Image   Stretch="Uniform" Height="77" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{TemplateBinding ??}" />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource ColumnHeadTemplate}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The template works, but now I'm stuck trying to set the Image Source for each Column, how can acomplish that?

**Edit 1**
After test

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeadTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid Height="82">
                        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Image   Stretch="Uniform" Height="77" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{Binding Path=Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"  />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource ColumnHeadTemplate}" Height="319" Width="1014">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/a_128.png"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/b_128.png"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/c_128.png"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Viewbox>
```

But the image is not displayed in the header

Answer (score 0):

You can bind image to the some property of `DataGridColumn`, for example to `Header` property. In that case `Image` code looks like this.

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" Height="60" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                                                 
       Source="{Binding Path=Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
```

And `Columns` code. I think you can use `Bindings` in the headers if you want.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="/WPFTest;component/Images/GPlus.png" Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="/WPFTest;component/Images/GMain.ico" Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**Update**

Another way. You can define button content in `Resources`.

```
<Image x:Key="testImage" Height="60" Width="100" Source="/WPFTest;component/Images/GPlus.png" />
<Image x:Key="testImage2" Height="60" Width="100" Source="/WPFTest;component/Images/GMain.ico" />
```

And should change the button in the `ControlTemplate`.

```
<Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Content="{Binding Path=Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
```

And `Columns`.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{StaticResource testImage}" Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{StaticResource testImage2}" Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I need but after tested doesn't work, the image is not displayed I edited post to clarify applied code

Comment: Maybe something wrong with images path. Is image displayed correctly if you add `<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/a_128.png" />` on some place in the window? Also I've used StaticResource for header style, but it also works with DinamicResource.

Comment: Yes, Actually i put a Image and set Source from the Source from the property manager and that was the string generated, and whish I put on Header

Comment: I've changed answer, maybe it helps. And you should test somewhere in window that image resources is displayed correctly. For example, create `Button` and set it's `Content` to `StaticResouce`.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the template which would be applied to all the column headers. If you want to use control-template and still want different images for individual headers, you can go for

1. [Style selectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector(v=vs.110).aspx),
2. If you still want to use TemplateBinding syntax, then you can get your ImageSource value in Button's Tag property and bind your Image's source like `<Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" />` in your current template .

If you want separate images for separate col headers, you can either

1. Hard code values in every column header like `<Image source = "img/headerimg1.png"/>` , or
2. Binding Source property like `<Image source = {x:Static local:SomeClass.Src1} />`.

   ```
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>                            
                    <Image Source="{x:Static local:SomeClass.Src1}"/>                                            
                   </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
   ```